# iPhone SDK, framework to handle api calls?

Tags: iphone

i am creating an iphone app, can someone suggest some framework to handle api calls to server (i am using coreData for my model)
there is one framework, restkit. but it requires backend to have a very specific format

is there any other framework/set of classes which can be easily customized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without knowing what sort of API you want to communicate with; does it follow some relatively well-known and well-defined structure? If not, there probably won't be a framework for it and you'll have to roll your own communication code. Looking into the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library would be a good starting point if this is the case.

Comment: what i had in mind is to have a general framework which can handle api calls for say a social-network app. i initially knew that i might have to create my own set of classes for that, but before starting any thing i just wanted to ask if there is any obvious solution.
thanks Chris for your response, I should get rolling now :)

Comment: If you're developing an app for an existing service, check if they provide their own framework. Facebook has one, for example. Good luck!